# Вставка сложных формул в диапазон GOOGLE SPREADSHEET

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Есть формула, которая ищет пустые ячейки в диапазоне столбца AC3(AC3:AC21) и выводит в отдельную ячейку соответствующие значения из ячеек диапазона C3:C21.

```
=TEXTJOIN(" "; FALSE;FILTER(C3:C21;AC3:AC21<=0))
```

Задача, которую не могу решить. Диапазон AC3:AC21 должен быть двумя формулами привязанными к поиску столбца с номером соответствующим сегодняшнему числу.
Этот поиск я смог сделать и он корректно выводит ячейку AC3 и AC21.

```
=ADDRESS(3;COLUMN(LOOKUP(DAY(today());E2:AI2));4)
```

ПРОБЛЕМА. Если я в первую формулу TEXTJOIN вместо диапазона ставлю формулы с ADDRESS то ничего не работает, пишет ошибку :

> В функции FILTER указан неверный диапазон. Требуемое число строк – 19,
> столбцов – 1. Фактическое число строк – 1, столбцов – 1.

Сама итоговая формула с ошибкой:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" "; FALSE;FILTER(C3:C21;ADDRESS(3;COLUMN(LOOKUP(DAY(today());E2:AI2));4):ADDRESS(21;COLUMN(LOOKUP(DAY(today());E2:AI2));4)<=0))
```

Как я понимаю у меня в неверном формате формируется диапазон в ADDRESS:ADDRESS.

p.s. обе формулы функционируют по отдельности и выводят всё корректно, но вместе - ошибка.

Comment: Потому что *address* формирует текст, а не.ссылку. оберните еев *indirect*

Comment: Спасибо! Вроде работает сегодня, проверю, когда завтра сменится день. Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0):

В итоге получилась следующего рода формула, которая работает:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" "; FALSE;FILTER(C3:C21;INDIRECT(ADDRESS(3;COLUMN(LOOKUP(DAY(today());E2:AI2));4)):INDIRECT(ADDRESS(21;COLUMN(LOOKUP(DAY(today());E2:AI2));4))<=0))
```